# Can you make the browser detect Javascript links on elements other than <a>

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser, single-page-application

On medium.com they have a clickable link on an h3 element, however the browser seems to know the URL that it will take you to and shows it in the bottom left side of the screen.

When I inspect element I see that this link is only an h3 element. It has a name attribute, an id and a class on it. There is no  element and there is no href.

I assume that they listen to the click event of this element and then redirect the user to the correct page, but what I don't understand is how google chrome knows that this is a link and even shows the url it will take you to.

Is this something the browser now supports? Is there a specific way of forcing the browser to show it?

[image: See that the title is clickable and in the bottom left side of the browser window you can see the url it will take you to when you hover on it]

Comment: can you provide, some more steps to see the scenario in that site ?

Comment: @KishoreSahas, Just scroll down a bit. You will find <h3> elements..

Comment: They assign a click event to the element then, using a bit of javascript, converts the text within the element to what the site wants as a url ( replaces the spaces with dashes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a `<a>` element, just further up the line:

[image: screenshot]

This would have been visible in your screenshot too, in the selector bar at the bottom:

[image: edited screenshot]

([Link to the page](https://medium.com/search?q=notation%20and%20me), if anyone is interested.)

Answer (score -1):

Yep, it can be done through a simple listener, eg in jQuery:

```
<h3 id="link1">Link1</h3>
```

And the codebehind:

```
$("#link1").click(function () {
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
});
```

Should work in any modern browser, but I'd say they'd all interpret it differently.  I'm not sure we really need to know why it works, just that it does - you could get in to asking how *anything* works in a browser.  Presumably they quickly parse all of the code as it is loaded so they know all of the possible events. Something like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Overview_of_Events_and_Handlers) might help.

Comment: This makes something *act* like a link, but it won't show the URL when hovering over the assigned element.

Answer (score -1):

But if not Siguza finde `<a href>`. I think chrom count dependecis and show redirect page or function. Status bar you can just turn off or on. Or change by "wrong" redirect like can you show "Im the best" take

`<a href="Im the Best!">test</a>`

show : `localhost34567/Im the Best!`   ---> ok not perfect :D but you can play with it and have better results.

https://superuser.com/questions/239202/turn-off-the-link-hover-statusbar-in-google-chrome